# WordPress: Get number of user posts with status draft and published

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to count the number of user posts with the status draft and published (combined).

There is the function `count_user_posts()` but it counts only published posts or all posts.
As I see it, there is no option to limit to a specific post status.

Is there an other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post-type',
    'post_author' => user_id,
    'post_status' => array( 'publish', 'draft' )    
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
$count = count( $query->get_posts() );
```

Hope help you.